# Sublime text и правило !important

Tags: css, sublime-text, text

Когда я начинаю писать !imp, Sublime text 3 не предлагает мне окончание !important. Что делать?

Comment: Если установлен плагин Emmet в Sublime Text, то просто ставите "!" и нажимаете таб.

Comment: пользоваться notepad ++ ;)

Comment: Спасибо! Работает "! + Tab" Надо только привыкнуть теперь )

Comment: @НиколайБаташов, скопируйте, пожалуйста, свой комментарий уже как ответ. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных + )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если установлен плагин Emmet в Sublime Text, то просто ставите "!" и нажимаете таб.